# .htaccess Mod Rewrite should not allow extra characters

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite

I have been working on my `.htaccess` file, to make navigation experience much easier.  According to the syntax provided by Apache Foundation `?` will only allow a character or word be written once or zero times, but that doesn't seem the case. For some reason its allowing me to duplicate as many characters I want. Below is the problem with more detail.

```
RewriteRule ^contact([/]?)$  contact.php
```

That line work's perfectly for what I want, but I would like to know why its allowing me to do this `localhost/contact////////////////////////` and not only `localhost/contact` or `localhost/contact/` as it is supposed to.

`localhost/contact////////////////////////` should go to the specified `404 HTTP ERROR` page.

This seems to be a problem with Apache as I have realised stackoverflow contains the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered//////

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line to send all the URLs with multiple slashes to 404 handler:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)/+(/\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ [L,R=404]
```

If for some reason you you want strip off multiple slashes use:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)/+(/\S*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2 [R=302,L,NE]
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is just the way Apache (and many other systems) interprets paths (see quote and links below) so I'm not sure if there is an answer to this.

Also I tried a couple of things with .htaccess and 2 or more consecutive slashes seem to be interpreted as a single slash. Unless there is a configuration option in Apache to disable this (or perhaps even something to disable this at an OS level which could in turn break other things), I don't think there will be an answer. (Happy to be corrected if there is a way though!)

> A pathname that begins with two successive slashes may be
>   interpreted in an implementation-defined manner, although more than
>   two leading slashes shall be treated as a single slash.

Source: [Pathname Resolution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_11) via [this Unix.StackExchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1919/73914) which has many more interesting links

Answer (score 1):

I actually posted an answer earlier today—or yesterday?—which I attempted to solve this issue, but you deleted it before I could post my modified ruleset which has been tested and works. So here it is for reference:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^contact(/.*)?$  contact.php [L,NE]
```

And this rewrite rule ensures that only `localhost/contact/` or `localhost/contact` gets rewritten. But something like `localhost/contactdasopidsai9asd9i` is just sent a proper `404`.

But in this question you bring up the case of `localhost/contact////////////////////////`. And `anubhava` has properly answered that case; his rewrite rule logic will work to send multiple slashes to a `404`. So if you combine what I have with what he has, I think you will have a decent solution to your issue:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)/+(/\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ [L,R=404]
RewriteRule ^contact(/.*)?$  contact.php [L,NE]
```